# x coordinate value of a child is negative inside its own parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making a "Range" slider - a `Slider` with 2 thumbs to denote an age range.

The values are tied to their corresponding `UserDefaults` value (using SwiftUI's `AppStorage` wrapper).

When I drag a thumb, it updates its `UserDefaults` value based on its new `position.location.x` coordinate.

Here is the View:

```
struct AgeSlider : View {
    @AppStorage("minAge") var minAge: Double = 18
    @AppStorage("maxAge") var maxAge: Double = 65
    @State var leftThumbMoving = false
    @State var rightThumbMoving = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack{
                Color.gray.opacity(0.4)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 2, alignment: .center)
                    .onAppear {
                        print("width: \(geo.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local).width)")
                    }
                HStack{
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(leftThumbMoving ? Color.orange.opacity(0.5) : Color.orange)
                        .position(x: CGFloat(self.minAge), y: 0)
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 15)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { position in
                                    self.leftThumbMoving = true
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(position.location.x, forKey: "minAge")
                                    print("x: \(position.location.x)")
                                }
                                .onEnded { position in
                                    self.leftThumbMoving = false
                                }
                        )
                        .onAppear {
                            print("width: \(geo.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local).width)")
                        }
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(rightThumbMoving ? Color.orange.opacity(0.5) : Color.orange)
                        .position(x: CGFloat(self.maxAge), y: 0)
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 15)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { position in
                                    self.rightThumbMoving = true
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(position.location.x, forKey: "maxAge")
                                }
                                .onEnded { position in
                                    self.rightThumbMoving = false
                                }
                        )
                }
                
            }
                }


    }
}
```

I'm trying to move to the next step, which is adjusting the formula so the range of the slider is between 18 and 65.

However the random `x` value is causing me problems. To give you an example, the first orange thumb below has an `x` value of `-130`:

[image]

Where exactly is this negative value coming from?

The 2nd thumb value is `60`.

Here is the parent view if you're curious:

```
struct Settings: View {
    let auth: UserAuth
    init(auth: UserAuth) {
        self.auth = auth
    }
    @AppStorage("minAge") var minAge: Double = 18
    @AppStorage("maxAge") var maxAge: Double = 65
    @State var showDeleteDialog = false
    @State var deleteText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
                NavigationView {
                    Form {
                        Section {
                            Text(String(Int(minAge))).foregroundColor(.orange)
                        }
                        Section {
                            Text("Max age")
                            AgeSlider()
                            Text(String(Int(maxAge))).foregroundColor(.orange)
                            
                        }
                    
                        Section {
                            Text("Details")
                            Text("Gender: \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "gender")?.capitalizingFirstLetter() ?? "Unknown")").foregroundColor(.gray)
                            Text("Birthday: \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "birthday") ?? "Unknown")").foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        Section {
                            Text("Account")

                            Button(action: { self.auth.goOffline() }){
                                Text("Logout")
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: DeleteAccount(auth: self.auth)){
                                Text("Delete Account")
                            }
                        }
                    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings")).accentColor(Color.orange)
                    
                }.accentColor(.black)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `ZStack` - which is throwing off the `x` value of its children.

By removing the parent `ZStack` - the child `x` values will then start from 0.

However if you need to keep the `ZStack`, an alternative fix is:

`ZStack(alignment: .leading)` - so the `x` value starts from the left of the `ZStack` container.